# Transfer time at LHR (T3 → T2 → SNN)

Tags: uk, transit, airports, lhr, short-connections

Arriving (T3) on an AA ORD flight and have 2 hours to transfer to an Aer Lingus flt to SNN (T2).

Will that be enough time to make it?

Comment: Are the flights on the same ticket or did you buy two separate tickets?

Comment: Separate tickets

Comment: I would change the LHR-SNN flight to the next later one. It may mean waiting an extra four hours at Heathrow, but that's preferable to the likely expense of having to buy a whole new ticket on the day. And in future, it's a good idea to prefer buying single tickets rather than separate ones, as the airline is responsible if you miss a connection, rather than you being responsible.

Comment: Thank you Michael....considered that later flight  option.  If we "miss" the 11:05 am wouldn't they credit me for that flight value against a later flight?  As you point out, AA and AL are not "partners" so a singular ticket would be an issue.

Comment: Officially, they are not in any way responsible for your connection. If you miss the check-in time, they can deny you boarding and and you'll forfeit the value of your ticket. Some carriers [will accommodate you](http://clubtraveler.hgvclub.com/plan-your-trip/flat-tire-rule-varies-delta-american-other-airlines) as a goodwill gesture, but others, especially low-cost-carriers, will rigidly enforce their contract and insist you purchase a new last-minute ticket. I don't know what Aer Lingus' policy is on this.

Comment: Although online sites may not show the through ticket, a human travel agent should have been able to get this written as a single ticket. However, the fare might have been worse. Full-fare tickets used to be (and probably still are, to cater to business travelers) conjoinable with flights on other airlines, even outside an alliance.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I'm not sure about that. Aer Lingus doesn't seem to have an interline agreement with American, and does with some of American's competitors. If Aer Lingus does rejoin the oneworld alliance, as some speculate may happen, that could certainly change in the future.

Comment: I think @ZachLipton is correct effective 2014. (I haven't bought a full-fare ticket in a while.)

Comment: @AndrewLazarus A typical ORD-DUB business class through fare is much cheaper (often better than 50% cheaper) than an ORD-LON fare, even if the former routes via LON. End-on-end construction is not the way to go to price this route.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that you have purchased two separate tickets (as in two unrelated transactions and neither airline knows about the other flight) will make things substantially more difficult.

If you bought the flights separately, you officially [can't use](http://www.heathrow.com/flight-connections) the Heathrow Connections service and will have to exit the plane and walk to arrivals, go through UK immigration (assuming you have the documentation needed to enter the UK, which is straightforward if you're a US Citizen, but may be less so otherwise), claim any checked luggage, take it through customs, get yourself to T2, check in any checked luggage, go through security, get to your gate, and board. As a practical matter, it appears that you could do so anyway if you can produce the boarding pass for your second flight (see comments below), but none of that helps you if you have checked bags.

The [walk](http://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/getting-around-heathrow/travel-between-terminals) between T3 and T2 is about 10 minutes and fairly straightforward.

You'd need to get to the Aer Lingus check-in counter [45 minutes](https://www.aerlingus.com/travel-information/check-in-options/airport/) before the departure time to check-in your bags. If you have no checked baggage, you may possibly be able to check-in online, which would save time. Officially, you [must be at the gate](https://www.aerlingus.com/travel-information/airport-information/boarding-times/) no later than the time on your boarding pass, which should be 30 minutes prior to departure. They will close the flight, if it is on-time, sometime before the departure time and will not allow you to board, even if the aircraft is still there.

I would say that this is not enough time. It could theoretically work if there are no lines at immigration or security and your bags come up quickly. It could easily fail if the AA flight is a bit late or there's a 45 minute wait for immigration. And if it doesn't work, Aer Lingus has no obligation to assist you, as you arranged the connection yourself and they aren't guaranteeing it.

Comment: Thank you Zach ....are US citizens....in first on the aa flight so should get off quicker and hopefully get bags quickly...AA said flights can be early so hope so...wonder if AA passenger assistance would/could speed up the process?

Comment: @Athomas Aer Lingus is in a competing airline alliance, so AA might not be willing to help you all that much. In fact, you may even find yourself on a plane with United livery!

Comment: First on AA is a big leg up: you get out of the plane early and there is a good chance your bags will show up first. Doesn't help with immigration so it's still dicey

Comment: You might. Good luck!

Comment: @ZachLipton There's nothing wrong with using flight connections on separate tickets. Even if you don't have a BP for the second flight, you can get one at the flight connections desk.

Comment: @Berwyn If you have checked bags, it certainly won't work (unless you manage to get the bags checked through, but that's not going to happen with airlines that don't interline like these ones). Without checked bags, you officially aren't supposed to be able to (see the bottom of [this page](http://www.heathrow.com/flight-connections)), but it may well be possible in practice if you already have a boarding pass.

Comment: @ZachLipton AA and EI do have a baggage interline agreement. Not sure AA will check-through on separate tickets though. I thought your comment was an absolute comment about using flight connections on separate tickets, not about retrieving checked baggage though.

Comment: @Berwyn Good to know. Officially, the Heathrow people say that you can't use flight connections on separate tickets with or without checked baggage. I've never done it personally with separate tickets, and could well see it working.

Comment: @ZachLipton Where does it say that? That doesn't really make sense to me. Ah, I see it. Well, it makes sense if you have checked luggage. But it makes no sense if you're hand baggage only

Comment: @Berwyn The page I linked (if "you have arranged your own flight connection" follow arrivals and change terminals yourself). And this [Flight Connections brochure](http://www.redfern-travel.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/BA-LHR-Flight-Connections_e-brochure.pdf) (page 6) if you "have booked your connecting flight separately to your arriving flight," you have to go through arrivals, then change terminals. [This page](http://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/getting-around-heathrow/travel-between-terminals) also says to go between terminals yourself if you don't have a connecting ticket.

Comment: @Berwyn I agree it doesn't make a ton of sense, but that's what they say. Now whether they insist upon it if you try to actually do it, boarding pass in hand, I'm not sure.

Comment: @ZachLipton They don't. They don't check your previous itinerary, just your BP for your next flight.

Comment: "If you bought the flights separately, you officially can't use the Heathrow Connections service" that simply is not true in practise, unless they need to collect a bag. They can simply get on the bus. In any case, since they are going to Ireland, they will need to pass through UK immigration anyway [because of the CTA arrangement], but not UK customs.

Comment: @Berwyn 99% of the time no one checks anything (except in the T5 DOM->INT corridor), and if they do, you simply say "I'll get it at the next terminal"

Comment: @Calchas I added a bit to reference this discussion. Of course, if someone has checked bags, they'll need to claim them anyway. And thanks to the CTA, immigration is involved in this connection one way or another.

Answer (score 5):

Since the OP has already booked tickets, I don't think any of the information I'm adding here is going to help much, but just to set the record straight.

According to [expertflyer](http://expertflyer.com), AA and EI do have ticketing and baggage interlining agreements. I can bring up a fare on matrix for ORD-AA-LHR-EI-SNN on a single AA fare which would have allowed through check of baggage to SNN.

Having an interline agreement doesn't mean that baggage must be interlined on separate tickets though, as that is down to the policies of the airlines. AA's policy appears to currently only interline to other oneworld airlines on separate tickets and even that is likely to change soon due to a recent oneworld policy change.

If you are following the same itinerary in reverse on the way back, Aer Lingus also state they will only [interline bags](http://classic.aerlingus.com/i18n/en/htmlPopups/baggageinformation.html) on the same ticket:

> Aer Lingus will through-check baggage as a courtesy onto any carrier
>   that have a baggage agreement in place, upon presentation of
>   documentation of the itinerary showing Aer Lingus and partner carrier
>   flights on the **same ticket**.
>
> This includes the following airlines:   **American Airlines**, Air France,
>   Air India, Alaska Airlines, Finnair, British Airways, Air China, China
>   Airlines, Cathay Pacific, China Southern, Emirates, Etihad, Gulf Air,
>   Iberia, Japan Airlines, KLM, Kenya Airways, Kuwait Airways, Malev,
>   Malaysian, Martin Air, Northwest, Austrian Airlines, Pakistan
>   Airlines, Qantas, Qatar Airways, South African Airways, Singapore
>   Airlines, Thai Airlines, United Airlines, Sri Lankan Airlines, US
>   Airways, Virgin Atlantic and JetBlue Airways.

Although Zach's references indicate that passengers travelling on separate tickets should not use flight connections, if you don't have checked baggage I see no reason why you should not use it. Your previous flights are of no importance, only your boarding pass for your next flight. If you have checked bags, that point is moot if your bags aren't interlined.

Comment: I would need professional help to book this onto the same ticket. The usual Internet sites won't.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus  I did a search on aa.com for ORD-SNN (with all carriers selected) and was offered AA46 ORD-LHR connecting to EI381 for LHR-SNN. It was on page 3 so not the most popular option